# What's the difference between application vs service frameworks?

Tags: spring, web, service, frameworks, cxf

I'm reading tutorial for Apache CXF and I see one of the samples is using Spring framework. Looking at the following example I don't understand how it is different from just using Spring (it seems CXF doesn't add any add'l functionality?) http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apache CXF** is a Services Framework which can be used to create web services and support  JAX-RS/JAX-WS/SAAJ  etc (various specifications for developing Web Services).

From there documentation they support the following:

> **Multiple Transports, Protocol Bindings, Data Bindings, and Formats**
>
> Transports: HTTP, Servlet, JMS, In-VM and many others via the Camel transport for CXF such as SMTP/POP3, TCP and Jabber
>
> Protocol Bindings:SOAP, REST/HTTP, pure XML Data bindings: JAXB 2.x, Aegis, Apache XMLBeans, Service Data Objects (SDO), JiBX
>
> Formats: XML Textual, JSON,FastInfoset
>
> Extensibility API allows additional bindings for CXF, enabling additional message format support such as CORBA/IIOP

Where as **Spring** is an Application Framework and supports

1. IOC Container / DI Framework
2. MVC Framework (Web Applications and Web Services support)
3. Data/JPA wrappers etc

To make your enterprise application creation experience smooth.